# Why can not Hostname of NiFi Certificate Authority be updated using NIFI-TOOLKIT?

Tags: apache-nifi

Toolkit to generate keystore and truststore with "-c 'hhh'",but the CN is 'localhost'?Can u get me suggestion?Thanks in  advance!

-c,--certificateAuthorityHostname    Hostname of NiFi Certificate Authority (default: localhost)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running the TLS Toolkit in `standalone` mode, and this is not the first invocation, you likely already have a `nifi-cert.pem` and `nifi-key.key` file in the working directory. These files are the CA public certificate and private key respectively. They will be reused to continue signing newly generated node certificates because this allows for trust across the different nodes of the cluster (which is the intended use case for the toolkit).

If you want to create a new CA certificate and use that to sign the node certificates, you have a few options:

1. Copy the toolkit build directory to a new location and invoke it there. Ensure that the `nifi-cert.pem` and `nifi-key.key` files are not present. On the first invocation, a new CA certificate and key will be generated, with the specified certificate authority hostname.
2. Delete the `nifi-cert.pem` and `nifi-key.key` files from your existing toolkit build directory. **Warning: You will no longer be able to sign certificates with the same CA key.** For example, if you generated `node1` and `node2` certificates signed by `CA_1`, then delete `CA_1` and want to add `node3`, you will not be able to sign `node3` with `CA_1`. You will have to import multiple public CA certificates (`CA_1` and the new `CA_2`, for example) into each node's truststore to allow for cross-trust.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -D in your command, to specify the CN and so on:

```
sudo bash tls-toolkit.sh client -c #YOUR_CA_HOST_FQDN -t #YOUR_CA_KEY_IF_ANY -p #CA_SERVER_PORT_IF_ANY -D "CN=#WHAT_EVER_YOU_WANT, OU=NIFI" -T PKCS12
```

Comment: Thanks,but this CMD is invaild

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem here, my solution was to remove de target file, as suggested in previous post, and run the script with an additional param, in your case it should be something like this

`tls-toolkit.sh standalone .... --certificateAuthorityHostname hhh`

It worked for me